# Hive/Impala count distinct on a partitioned column results in all data files being read?

Tags: hadoop, hive, distinct, impala

When querying a hive table according to a partitioning column, it would be logical that a simple

```
select count(distinct partitioned_column_name) from my_partitioned_table
```

would complete almost instantaneously.

But we are seeing that both hive and impala are unable to execute this query properly: they just read the entire table!

What do we need to do to ensure the above command executes rapidly?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hack, if the column is partitioned - it is bound to be distinct in warehouse dir.

You could try something like:

```
hadoop fs -ls /<hive_warehouse_directory>/<database.db>/<table_name> | wc -l
```

Usually, hive warehouse is kept as /user/hive/warehouse

Comment: Yes we are aware of this - but are looking to understand how/if to get this resolved properly in sql.